# Any chance an exception could be made for a LibreOffice 3.4 update -- so Natty can get Global Menus?

Tags: unity, libreoffice, globalmenu

Just wondering if we will all have to wait 6 months to get Global Menu support in LibreOffice?

It'd be nice if Ubuntu made one exception and updated LibreOffice to 3.4 so we could get Global Menus for it.

Answer (score 4):

To install Global Menu support for LibreOffice.

Install [`lo-menubar`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lo-menubar)[image: Install lo-menubar] from *Ubuntu Software Centre*

or in Terminal use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
```

Comment: is buggy and doesn't always work. Has 4 open bugs last I checked.

Comment: True; it's a good thing you pointed that out. However, the original poster seemed quite eager to have such a function, and it's quite usable in my experience, so this is probably the best solution at this point.

Comment: dang, too slow, beat me to it